# Confusion in taking derivatives using the derivative formula

Tags: calculus, derivatives, chain-rule

I've been stuck with this problem for a long time and can not figure out what I am doing wrong. Here is the question:

Given the  function f(x) = (2x)/(x+1)^2 find the tangent line at point (0,0).

My problem lies in taking the derivative of the function. Using the quotient rule combined with the chain rule, I get

f`(x) = (2(x+1)-4x(x+1))/(x+1)^4. This is correct and at x=0 the slope of the tangent line is 2.

My problem is when I tried (several times) to mimic the result by using the derivative formula. No matter how many times I tried, I got the result 1/0 = 0.

Here is what I did.

f`(x) = f(((x+h)-f(x)))/h when h approaches 0.

since I want the derivative where x = 0, I replaced this with:

f`(x) = (f(h) - f(0)) / h

since f(0) = 0

f`(x) = f(h)/h

so we get:

(2h/(h+1)^2 )   / h as h approaches zero.

I know this is wrong but I cannot understand where I erred. I would greatly appreciate an explanation of where I went wrong and how to properly calculate this derivative using the formula.

Comment: Please first try to learn $\LaTeX$ from https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: In the expression for $f’$ the first appearance of $(x+1)$ should be $(x+1)^2$ instead.

Comment: You were almost there, and everything looks correct in what you wrote, except for the result "$1/0 = 0.$" I don't see how you got that from anything else that you wrote. But I guess the posted answer has explained what your next step should have been, so all is OK now.

Comment: I kept multiplying by h instead of 1/h to simplify. Stupid, I know, but I was stuck in a rut and couldn't figure out my error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\frac{2h/(h+1)^2}{h} = 2 \frac{1}{(h+1)^2} \to 2 \quad \text{as $h \to 0$}$$

Comment: Thank you so much. It was really pretty simple but sometimes if you are stuck doing something the wrong way you need someone else's input :)